# How to speed up conda's package installation process?

Tags: python, conda

I'm using a conda environment in a corporate machine behind a specific proxy (via `https_proxy`). When I attempt to install packages via conda install, it reads from the proxy at the very last attempt. This implies that every time I try to install anything it will take >5m before reaching the right address.

I was wondering whether there's a way to avoid conda to scan unavailable http addresses and point straight to the right proxied one.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you defining the proxy?

Comment: It would also be helpful to know which operating system and which conda you are using